# $ x^{3}-x+a=0 $ and a is an uneven integer, show the polynomial has no rational root (Q)

Tags: polynomials

I know it's probably easy, but don't know how to prove exactly. I know roots are the divisors of a0/an and about viete, but I don't know if the proof is enough, please help

Comment: But $a_n = 1$.  That's a *huge* limitation.  And $a$ is odd.... so what about $x^3 - x +a=(x+1)x(x-1) + a$.  Can that ever equal $0$ if $x|a$ and $a$ is odd.  What about $x$? Is $x$ an integer? is it odd or even?  Does it matter?

Comment: By the rational root test any rational root is an integer, but there are no integer roots by the Parity Root Test in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sortof not really a trick question.

The rational root theorem so that if there is a rational root it is of the form $\pm \frac mn$ where $m|a$ and $b|1$.

The only thing that divides $1$ is $\pm 1$ so if there is a rational root it is $\pm m$ where $m|a$.

So if there is any rational root it is an integer.

What's more, as $a$ is odd then $m|a$ means $m$ is odd and so if there is any rational root it is an odd integer.

.....

But the thing is: If $x$ is an odd integer then $x^3 - x$ will always be even.

And if $a$ is *not* even then $x^3 - x + a$ will not be even.  So $x^3 - x +a =0$ is impossible.

Recap:

By rational root theorem the only rational roots of polynomial with leading coefficent of $1$ will be integers.

For any integer input, then $x^3 - x + a$ will always be odd and thus can not have any integer roots.

Comment: oh ok, everything the other persons said makes sense, thank aswell !

Answer (score 2):

Any rational root would have to be an odd integer.  But if $x$ is an odd integer, $x^3 - x + a$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

By the rational root theorem the roots would have to be odd integers (because they would be divisors of $a$), and odd integers give an odd result.

Comment: so if we get like 2 roots with the rational root theorem, then the third one can't be rational, it can be complex or something else?

Comment: Don't think about factoring the polynomial, just think about the fact that $Q(x)$ cannot be $0$ if $x$ is an odd integer.

Comment: yes, that is true, but you don't get all roots with the theorem, why can't the remaining ones be rational? sorry if it's dumb from me

Comment: Well, your original problem asks about rational roots, and the theorem tells you that rational roots are odd integers. We do not care about non-rational roots for the purpose of your problem.

Comment: oh ok, I understood the point , thanks a lot

Comment: "why can't the remaining ones be rational"  The only possible denominators are $1$ (and negative $1$).

Comment: "then the third one can't be rational, it can be complex or something else?"  Or irrational real.  Actually you can't have just *one* complex root (but that's another story).  And you *don't* get 2 rational roots.  You get $0$ rational roots.  Either there are $3$ irrational real roots, or $1$ irrational real root and $2$ complex roots.  But we weren't *asked* about that.  We were only asked to show there there are no *rational* roots; we weren't asked anything about what the roots actually *are*.